# ionic 3 Mac build ios cordova-plugin-ionic-webview got error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, ionic3

i am using ionic 3 to build my app. However i am facing an error when i try to build the ios on Mac. Here is the error massage:

> CompileC /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.o MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/emulator/include -I/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/emulator/usr/local/lib/include -I/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/include -I/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/emulator -I/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/emulator -include /Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch/MyApp-Prefix-ecbvllkeqtjuzsgpgfagkkqzoohs/MyApp-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.dia -c /Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m -o /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.o
>   /Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m:59:10: error: no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'appendData:'
>     [_data appendData:data];
>      ~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
>   1 error generated.
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC /Users/myPC/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hddsubveawhvtmayjrerdpieryqd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GCDWebServerDataRequest.o MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/GCDWebServerDataRequest.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>   Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,MyApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,MyApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/myPC/Desktop/Gary/ionic/myNewTest/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).

i also facing this problem when i try to build a new fresh project, i am not sure what is the problem. As it is working on building Android with Window System.

Also it is working to build ionic 1 project on this mac but facing problem after i update all the environment to ionic 3 so i am not sure is that any problem with xcode version
Here is the info of the ionic

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.9.3
npm   : 5.5.1 
OS    : OS X El Capitan
Xcode : Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4

You are using the latest `cordova-ios` (currently 4.5.4) platform in your app. The minimum Xcode version supported is Xcode 8. Check [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/upgrade.html).

> NOTE: Xcode 8 is required. Currently, to submit to the Apple App Store, you should use the latest shipped version of the iOS SDK, which is iOS 10 and this is included only with Xcode 8.

You need to upgrade Xcode from 7.1.1 to 8 atleast or even 9.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, currently i am using VM to create a mac environment to build the ios and i cannot upgrade the xcode since the OS are also in a very old version which not allow me to upgrade it. So in this situation, should i downgrade the Cordova Platforms Or find another Mac image? Any suggestion or alternative way i can solve it?

Comment: I think you will have to figure out a way to upgrade your system if you plan on releasing to app store.. Downgrading cordova _might_ build your app but you wont be able to release..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use sudo especially when making/overwriting files.